# Loading class attributes in Yii2

Tags: yii2

For example I have the following classes:

```
class A extends yii\base\Model {
    public $attr1;
    public $attr2;
}

class B extends yii\db\ActiveRecord {
    ... some attributes in table including attr1 and attr2 ...
}
```

Is it more elegant way to load() values from object B to object A than

```
$objectA = new A();
$objectB = new B();
... obtaining values for $objectB ...
$objectA->load([StringHelper::basename($objectB->className()) => $objectB->attributes])
```

?

Answer (score 0):

You can do a

```
$objectA->attributes = $objectB->attributes;
```